# How to make my binary to decimal conversion program also read 0s?

Tags: java, exception, binary, decimal

This program is supposed to convert binary numbers to decimal and throws the exception when the input has non-binary numbers. This program will read 1s, but when I input 0s, it will throw the exception and tell me it's not binary.

Test Program:

```
//Prepare scanner from utility for input.
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bin2Dec {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        //Convert the input string to their decimal equivalent.
        //Open scanner for input.
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Declare variable s.
        String s;

        //Prompt user to enter binary string of 0s and 1s.
        System.out.print("Enter a binary string of 0s and 1s: ");
        //Save input to s variable.
        s = input.nextLine();
        //With the input, use try-catch blocks.
        //Print statement if input is valid with the conversion.
        try {
            System.out.println("The decimal value of the binary number "+ "'" + s + "'" +" is "+conversion(s));
            //Catch the exception if input is invalid.
        } catch (BinaryFormatException e) {
            //If invalid, print the error message from BinaryFormatException.
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    //Declare exception.
    public static int conversion(String parameter) throws BinaryFormatException {
        int digit = 0;
        for (int i = parameter.length(); i > 0; i--) {
            char wrong_number = parameter.charAt(i - 1);
            if (wrong_number == '1') digit += Math.pow(2, parameter.length() - i);
            //Make an else statement and throw an exception.

            else if (wrong_number == '0') digit += Math.pow(2, parameter.length() - i);

            else 
                throw new BinaryFormatException("");
        }
        return digit;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Right where you have `// Make an else ...` add `else if (wrong_number == '0') { ... }`. That would avoid letting `wrong_number == '0'` fall through to the `throws` statement.

Comment: it's not giving me the right conversion

Answer (score 1):

This program only accepts '1' as char due to these lines:

```
if (wrong_number == '1') digit += Math.pow(2, parameter.length() - i);
          //Make an else statement and throw an exception.
else 
    throw new BinaryFormatException("");
```

Since there's no `if(wrong_number == '0')`, the number will only accept 1s and throw an exception when encountering a 0.

Apart from that:
Avoid `Math.pow`, if possible in any way. Since it's quite resource intensive and in this case completely useless. 2^x can be generated a lot easier using bit-shifting:

```
int pow_2_x = (1 << x);
```

And finally: java already provides a [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) for this:

```
int dec = Integer.parseInt(input_string , 2);
```

Comment: where do I put those? When i remove "Math.pow(2, parameter.length() - i);" and replace it with "int pow_2_x = (1 << x);", it doesn't work

Comment: @agentmg123 you shouldn't insert the entire line, just replace `Math.pow...` with `1 << (parameter.length() - i - 1)` and that `else if(wrong_number == '0') digit += ...` statement doesn't exactly make sense. If the bit is 0, you shouldn't add anything. Simplest solution would be `else if(wrong_number != '0') throw BinaryFormatException("");`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your logic. Since you are dealing with binary numbers ('1' and '0') but you are checking for 1 only you should check for '0' also and throw exception only if it's other than '0' ans '1'

```
if (wrong_number == '1') digit += Math.pow(2, parameter.length() - i);
//Make an else statement and throw an exception.


else 
    throw new BinaryFormatException("");
```

Comment: that's not helpful at all. Be more specific about **what exactly** is the logic mistake made in this code